# TFS 2010 - Portal settings

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

It doesn't appear that you can modify the base url for the portal settings in TFS 2010. I currently have

```
http://tfsserver.mydomain.com
```

I would like the system to launch

```
http://tfsserver
```

instead when a user selects 'Show project portal' from Team Explorer.

Is it possible to change the site root that it points to? We keep getting security prompts with fqdn.

Comment: FYI you should be able to setup a SPN record to stop the security prompts from occurring.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This was happening in SharePoint but I didn't know about SPns.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. On the application tier, open the admin console, select SharePoint Web Applications and change the base url there.